# In ArrayList.trimToSize(), why is modCount bumped if no structural changes actually happened

Tags: java

For example:

```
public void trimToSize() {
    modCount++;
    if (size < elementData.length) {
        elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size);
    }
}
```

Why isn't the `modCount` increment inside the if?

It seems as if `modCount` counts the structural modification intention rather than the effective structural modification.

Comment: What are you trying to ask? It's totally unclear..

Comment: No clue what you're trying to ask about. If you're actually asking why `modCount` gets incremented even if your `if statement` doesn't pass, that's because it's outside the `if statement`.

Comment: Looks like question is about java.util.ArrayList::trimToSize().

Comment: tnw, I think that we all get this. The question is "Why is it not in the if block"
I thought that my sentence: "Why isn't the modCount increment inside the if?" was explicit enough

Comment: At a guess?  Because calling it at all indicates that you're _trying_ to modify the list, which reflects a bug even if you got lucky this time.

Comment: @Ngx472 That was edited in after I commented.

Comment: The OP is asking why in jdk source code some function that may modify the data structure are flagging a modification even when there is none. The question is legitimate. The answer is certainly that the flag shows more an intention than an actual change.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the implementation of `ArrayList`, I don't see why `trimToSize()` and `ensureCapacity()` both increment `modCount`. They don't change the *logical* view of the list even when there is an actual re-allocation of the `elementData` array.

`modCount` is used to ensure that an object that has a *view* (iterator, sublist) on the list can detect a modification (add, remove, set) on the underlying list.

In single thread environment, what scenario could actually invalidate an iterator on the list by calling `ensureCapacity()`? since the iterator is storing logical indexes that **do not** change while calling `trimToSize()` or `ensureCapacity()`.

A reason (I guess from my understanding of the source code) for `ensureCapacity()` to increment `modCount` is that it is called by all `add()` family methods (there is even a comment in `add()` **not to** do `modCount++` **since** it is done by `ensureCapacity()`).

I may be wrong - and there is a possibility for these 2 methods to invalidate an iterator -, but if it is not the case, the reason advanced by some commenters to flag an *intend* to modify the list does not hold:

- `trimToSize()` sizes the internal array to remove unused *slots*. These are never used by iterators or sublists and there is no intention from the user/caller to *modify* the list content. The only intention is to save some memory.
- The case of `ensureCapacity()` is exactly the same: there is no possibility to *shrink* a list. If a user call this method, it's for optimisation and do some right-sizing before adding elements.

As a final thought, I would go further: a user should not expect some `ConcurrentMdificationException` in an iteration when calling either of these methods.

Comment: `trimToSize()` doesn't change the logical view of the `List`, but it does change the reference to the `Object[]` storing the `List`'s elements. It is therefore essential for it to be considered a structural modification. Suppose `iterator.remove()` and `trimToSize()` are running concurrently. You could get the following problem. (1) `Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size);` in `trimToSize()` begins. (2) `iterator.remove()` moves array elements along one place, (3) `trimToSize()` replaces the `Object[]` by the (copy of) the version that existed **before** `remove` moved the elements.

Comment: If you are in a multi-thread environment, you must use a synchronized `ArrayList`, e.g. with `Collections#synchronizedList(...)`. This should not allow some the situation you describe. See [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List)) on the subject and how to use an iterator in MT env.

Comment: I agree that you shouldn't be using `ArrayList` in a multi-threaded environment, but my point is that it's still useful for `ArrayList` to throw a `ConcurrentModificationException` if it detects that you are. Having `trimToSize()` increase `modCount` is not strictly necessary, but it's an incredibly cheap operation that will increase the chances of bugs being detected if programmers accidentally use `ArrayList` when they shouldn't. From this point of view I think it makes sense to increase `modCount` as early as possible in the method.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#modCount and various SO questions modCount is used to track modifications that may be done concurrently to an iteration process.

If we assume that a method will throw an exception whenever modCount changes, this effectively means ArrayList will react to the intention, as you say, notifying the user that something is trying to change it.